# Passing bundles through activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a bundle that I want to pass through more than one activity.

Consider this example. I have activity1, activity2 and activity3. Activity1 goes to Activity2. Activity2 goes to Activity3. I want to get information from activity1 to activity3

My code would be

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra(KEY, "Straight There");
startActivity(intent);
```

and then I would have to do this in Activity2

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) 
        text = extras.getString(KEY);
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity3.class);
intent.putExtra(KEY, text);
startActivity(intent);
```

Is there anyway I can pass the whole bundle through the activity without having to parse the keys and rebundle?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [putExtras(Intent src)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras(android.content.Intent)) to pull all the extras out of one `Intent` and put them into another.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity3.class);
intent.putExtras(getIntent()); // get all the extras out of the current Activities Intent
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
intent.putExtras(getIntent());
```

Comment: Should be rather: `intent.putExtras(getIntent().getExtras());`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use SharedPreferences to avoid passing data activity by activity,like this:
in your first activity,save data by SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString(KEY, "Straight There");
```

in your third activity,get data by SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
String result = settings.getString(KEY, null);
```

more info about SharedPreferences,see:[Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)